# How to store in a file text line by line in python *** with an input ***

Tags: python, file

I've been trying to store in a text file my code but its always stored in one line even if i use more than 1 input and even command as /n or a for loop. Here is my code :

```
file = open("text.txt",'w+')


file.write(input('Entrer la première chaîne (minimum 4 caractères):'))
file.write(input('Entrer la deuxième chaîne (minimum 1 caractères):'))
```

The reason why im using w+ is that im gonna need to read this code in the same program. No matter what i do im only able to store them in my file on the same line... If i remove input from my code im able to use /n as expected. Any thoughts?

Here are my instructions if you need more info :

your program must ask the user to enter two strings and then store it in a text file as text.txt. then, your program must read the contents of the file (1st line represents the 1st chain and the 2nd line represents the 2nd chain) and do the processing to display on the screen the 2 channels as well as the number of occurrences of the second chain in the first.

I am able to code the occurences, my problem is with the file.

I have been looking through the website and i cant find anything that will help me since im stuck because of my input command and not only the readlines().

Comment: The slash went the wrong way when you tried the newline escape sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
file.write(input('Entrer la première chaîne (minimum 4 caractères):'))
file.write(input('Entrer la deuxième chaîne (minimum 1 caractères):'))
```

To:

```
file.write(input('Entrer la première chaîne (minimum 4 caractères):')+'\n')
file.write(input('Entrer la deuxième chaîne (minimum 1 caractères):')+'\n')
```

You will need to manually handle the newline characters on the end of each line. Also remember to close your file pointer `file` with `file.close()` once your done using it to ensure a clean exit.